# Post back to the previous page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I need to post back to the previous page where I fetch some output in datatable by search method. I need those search value to retain in the page when I navigate from another page. For instance if i'm in a searchPage.aspx I obtain the search results in the datatable from there when I click a row I will be redirected to another page (View.aspx). From View.aspx I need to post back to the Search.aspx and also I need the values to retain there.

Comment: Your question seems need more info.

Comment: @5ervant : I have edited my question. Hope that will help to sort this out.

Comment: How about using Session?

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz: In session what values will u hold on?

Comment: Are you sure you're using MVC? Typically aspx files are used in WebForms.

Comment: @AarthiRavendiran: The results of the previous search?

Comment: @Brian: I told jst for an simplee example. I'm using MVC only

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz: Can you explain?